# Sending emails from different address

Tags: node.js, email, meteor

I have a system (`Meteor`) where employees log in.
I would like to send and email to clients from the system and set sender email depending on who is logged in.
(I know what email server/username/password employee has)

Eg. When `John` is log in, he should have an option to send and email from `john@test.com`, but when `James` is log in he should have an option to send and email from `james@test.com`

How can I achieve this? How to dynamically change `mail_url`?

Comment: Just use cookies and sessions? bind them with the system?!

Comment: Do you mean, actual user on SMTP server is `xyz@somedomain.com` but when `john` logs in then you want sender of mail as `john@test.com`? Or `john@test.com` itself is a valid user on SMTP server.

Comment: @sameerkn Exactly, actual user on SMTP server is xyz@somedomain.com but when john logs in then I want set sender of mail as john@test.com :)

Comment: In this case you need to ensure that `mail_url`  has details of actual user `xyz@somedomain.com` and `from` field while composing SMTP message has `john@test.com`

Comment: @sameerkn thank you, Will such messages not be spammed? As unauthorized emails?

Comment: Most probably it won't get spammed. Because the `from` field is used to just show the name of sender.